# Kendo UI grid URL Column

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to add a hyperlink in my Kendo UI Grid. from data source I am getting a URL back and I just want to to display it as a hyperlink . below is a sample code . Please suggest me the simplest way to do that.

```
 <div id="testGrid" data-role="grid" data-bind="source: sampleData"
data-sortable="true"  data-resizable="true" />

$(document).ready(function(){
var sampleData = [
    { "Title": "The Code Project", "URL": "http://codeproject.com/","Developer":"Tom Hanks" },
    { "Title": "Kendo UI", "URL": "http://kendoui.com/" ,"Developer":"Tom Cruise"}
];
var ddatasource=  new kendo.data.DataSource.create(sampleData);
$("#testGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ddatasource,
    columns: [{ field: "Title", title: "Title Name"},
              { field: "URL", title: "URL :"}]
});
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to do any research or make any attempt at all?  If so, include that in your post.  People will want to help you if you first show some effort.

Comment: Hi Rick, I did tried to search and got some articles for using template but was not clear how to use in my scenario as I am getting the data from a Web API and the columns in my actual code are using declarative initialization using data-columns.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this with a template:

```
columns: [{ field: "Title", title: "Title Name"},
          { field: "URL", title: "URL :", template: '<a href="#=URL#">#=Title#</a>'}]
```

You can try it out on the Kendo Dojo here: http://trykendoui.telerik.com/aFAR

Comment: Hi Rick, when I am specifying the template section in Declative initialization in "Data-columns" its throwing error. I am able to do what is desired using a <Table> and creating a template which forms the TR with URL but now the issue is that the alternate row stying is not being imposed.

Comment: Please update the kendo dojo code linked to in my answer so I can see what's going on.

Comment: Never mind. Id got rid of declarative stuff and you code worked for me....Thanks a ton for the help.